# Cannot read property of undefined which is set to null in data return by vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

My data is as follows:

```
data() {
return {
  testing: null,
  totD: null,
  totA: null,
  allData: []
};
```

},

My function function is as follows:

```
postData("https://114.143.112.190:20443/jw_web/jwbiservice.asmx/jwBiService", searchParams).then(data => {
    return this.testing = data; // JSON data parsed by `response.json()` call
  });
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWEz6.png)

```
13.js:332 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'testing' of undefined
at _callee2$ (13.js:332)
at tryCatch (65.js:66)
at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (65.js:292)
at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (65.js:118)
at asyncGeneratorStep (13.js:120)
at _next (13.js:122)
at 13.js:122
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at 13.js:122
at _postData2 (13.js:357)
```

This error occurred.
I can use `this.testing` in template but unable to access in next method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because of the arrow function，try this one:

```
.then(function (data) {
    return this.testing = data; // JSON data parsed by `response.json()` call
  })
```